# Visual Studio IIS HTTP 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2013

I have searched every topic and it seems that everyone got there problem solved already and I have tried all the possible solution they have provided or I am still missing something.

- FireWall already turned off.

Ok so I am trying to access my IIS server Application that is currently run by VS 2013. Update 2.

when I try to access http://localhost:29790/ <- this to http://192.168.1.3:29790 which is my current IP on my local. It gives me 503 error.

I have searched for the solution and gives my a tons of.

applicationhost.config file

```xml
<site name="SMApplication(4)" id="10">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\DanZe3\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SMApplication\SMApplication" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:29790:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

I have tried this.

- `*:29790:*`
- `*:29790:`
- `:29790:`

by chaining the bindings. But it is still not working. I restart the PC or the VS as well. But the problem is, when I try to re-open VS. VS overwrite the *applicationHost.config* and add another binding.

As you can see in my site named "SMApplication(4)"  (It has made 4 already!) This is automatic when I re-open the file
and then the bindings will be `*:29790:localhost` again.

Somehow Editing this bindings. Visual Studio will create another binding of the application, having another site named SMApplication(5).

I have tried to remove the localhost on the `*:29790:localhost`, but when I run the application it gives me.

Unable to Launch IIS Express Web Server.
The start URL specified is not a valid. http://localhost:29270/

Answer (score 28):

I had a similar problem with a similar solution:

Scenario: I had the app pool running under an user account and it's password had been changed because it had expired. I never updated IIS so the app pool would stop by itself every time when a try to run website. Even if I start AppPool manually, It stopped on website run.

Solution: update the credentials for the account on IIS or use another account

Comment: In my particular case, I had set my login credentials on the Application Pool.  Solution: Application Pools | <service with 503 error> | Advanced Settings... | Identity (where it currently shows my login) | <press elipsis (...)>   Enter fully qualified login <DOMAIN\USER> and password.  Fixed.

Answer (score 9):

I
Application's DefaultAppPool (or other custom name) may have stopped for some reason.  Make sure it is on.  Recycle too.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this issue recently after Windows 10 update (Dev machine). 
I have created a new IIS AppPool and assigned to the website and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to remove IIS Express folder at %USERPROFILE%\Documents.

Next important thing is to restart Visual Studio and open it as admin.

Then you can right click your ASP.NET project and go into Properties view. There you can configure web settings for IIS hosting in the Web tab. Try to change IIS settings here and then save with Ctrl+S.

When there is a * next to the web tab because you tried to edit settings but could not save, you need to change to another tab, switch back to Web tab and then save with Ctrl+S. (The Properties view for ASP.NET apps in Visual Studio is still buggy ...)

I am currently using Visual Studio 2015 CE so I don't know whether my solution applies to your problem. Anyways try to remove any folders that got cached by IIS Express hosting and never really got cleaned up afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

So, in my case the only thing that fixed this was setting the ip statically in a new binding protocol, in your case would be something like this:

```
<site name="SMApplication(4)" id="10">
      <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\DanZe3\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SMApplication\SMApplication" />
      </application>
      <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:29790:localhost" />
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:29790:192.168.1.8" />
      </bindings>
 </site>
```

This won't cause any problem in a production environment.